# how to register multiple SocketChannel on one thread with a Selector on different thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, socketchannel

I am developing an Android app in which I am using SocketChannel with Selector for sending network requests to my server.

I have a selector on one threads which has registered for `OP_CONNECT`, `OP_WRITE` and `OP_READ` and which calls the `select()` method to receive these events.

can anybody suggest me correct way of doing the multi-threaded registration of SocketChannel with a single Selector ?

Answer (score 1):

The time-consuming part is the actual read from/write to the channels. So basically you would

1. Set up a set of socket channels
2. Register all them to a selector.
3. In your main selection thread call `select()`. Once return value > 0, get the set of selection keys and determine if you want to read/write on the associated channels.
4. Create a thread pool. Do all your actual read/write to the channels by that pool. Or even, cache your `Runnable` instances if you want zero object loop.